# ionic 4 cameraPreview plugin takes picture without even tapping

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i am using cordova CameraPreview plugin with ionic4. it's showing as i needed but it does not wait for tap to take picture. it just takes a pic automatically without even waiting.

```
async openCamera(){

    const cameraPreviewOpts: CameraPreviewOptions = {
      x: 0,
      y: (window.screen.height - (window.screen.width*2/3) - 200),
      width: window.screen.width,
      height: (window.screen.width*2/3),
      camera: 'rear',
      tapPhoto: true,
      tapToFocus: true,
      previewDrag: false,
      toBack: false,
      alpha: 1
    }

    await this.cameraPreview.startCamera(cameraPreviewOpts)

      const pictureOpts: CameraPreviewPictureOptions = {
        quality: 25
      }

       this.presentToast('Tap on the image to capture it')
      // take a picture
      this.cameraPreview.takePicture(pictureOpts).then((imageData) => {
            this.cameraPreview.stopCamera();

      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        alert('failed')
      });


  }
```

Comment: according to your code  you should put openCamera() on button click then you can use it .

Comment: @MoblizeIT  this.cameraPreview.takePicture use this method inside a button click where preview is visible

Comment: not sure where is the confusion? the takePicture is inside openCamera which gets invoked on the button click. i see that starts the preview. as per settings it should wait for user to tap but it does not.  that's the only problem